# Git is seeing changes I didn't make in xcode

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore

I'm programming in xcode (actually Phone Gap in conjunction with xcode) with git. I'm having a strange issue. When I create two identical branches and try to check out back and fourth between them with out making any changes git is telling me that I need to commit because a change has been made (this same thing is also resulting in merge conflicts). It says the changed file is:

```
platforms/ios/Butterfli.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/benpearce.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Can anyone explain what's going on and how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [.xcworkspaces are simply files that Xcode uses to describe the workspace or projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956312/is-the-project-xcworkspace-file-important).

IMHO, There's no need to check these files in at all, unless you share settings with other folks in your projects (and in your case, I suppose other machines that have a user named "`benpearce`").

In fact, you can safely add them to your `.gitignore` file.

More info [can be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939421/what-should-xcode-5-gitignore-file-include/18939465)

Comment: I'm a bit of a git/unix noob. Is the command for that "git ignore *.xcworkspaces"?

Comment: you have to edit the "`.gitignore`" file that lives in the root of your git repo, which in your case would be the same folder your "`platforms`" source code folder lives in.  You can use a Macintosh text editor (making certain the file remains a plain text file with no "`.txt`" extension) or you can use "`emacs`" or "`vi`" in Terminal.

Comment: Since it's already tracked you need to also run `git rm --cached  unwanted_path`. Only Then git will ignore the specifued files

Comment: Thanks for the info everyone, I'm still trying to get this implemented properly. @MichaelDautermann is ".DS_Store build" in the example supposed to be the path to my xcodeproject?

Comment: @kaman when I run your command I get "fatal: not removing 'platforms/ios/{project_name}.xcodeproj' recursively without -r"

Comment: That means you specified path to a directory not a file.