# "no such module" on Xcode 7 beta 2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, carthage, xcode7-beta2

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/xcode-no-such-module-error-but-the-framework-is-there), but I am still unable to import a framework and use it inside Xcode 7 beta 2 (7A121l).

So currently I am trying to use [Result](https://github.com/antitypical/Result), via carthage. After adding it to *Build Phases/ Link Binary with Binaries* and *Embed Frameworks* I am able to compile successfully, but I get an error stating (yes it says success and then error :S):

```
No such module 'Result'
```

On the import:

```
import Result

func serverRequest() -> Result<String, NSError> {
    ...
}
```

The build is able to Run and Compile, but I am not able to cmd+click on Result, for example.

---

**Edit 1:**
On Xcode 6.3.2 it works as expected.

**Edit 2:**
Opened a radar: 21588771

Comment: it happened same to my Xcode 7 Beta 2 and ReactiveCocoa. I deleted from embedded framework, add it again, quit Xcode, restart computer. I don't know when but now it doesn't show any code completion error. Weird here too.

Comment: Are you still having this problem on Beta 3?

Comment: @AndyIbanez Following the above mentioned approach, it's working.

Comment: Make sure you are not having a `d'oh` moment: check that you have opened the .xcworkspace not the .xcodeproj

Comment: @TomHoward why would it matter?

Comment: It wouldn't necessarily @RuiAAPeres; it is dependent upon how your project is structured. Little background: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10960309/1803879

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neil's answer is right, but there a very subtle difference how you set the `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS`. So after adding it only to `Build Phases/ Link Binary with Binaries`, my initial setup was like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x   8 ruiperes  staff    272 29 Jun 08:35 Playground
drwxr-xr-x   5 ruiperes  staff    170 29 Jun 22:08 Playground.xcodeproj
drwxr-xr-x   4 ruiperes  staff    136 29 Jun 00:12 PlaygroundTests
drwxr-xr-x   4 ruiperes  staff    136 29 Jun 00:12 PlaygroundUITests
drwxr-xr-x   8 ruiperes  staff    272 29 Jun 08:42 Result.framework


FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(SRCROOT)/**
```

**The above is the wrong setup** and won't work. **The working one below**:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 ruiperes  staff    136 29 Jun 22:07 Frameworks
drwxr-xr-x   8 ruiperes  staff    272 29 Jun 08:35 Playground
drwxr-xr-x   5 ruiperes  staff    170 29 Jun 22:08 Playground.xcodeproj
drwxr-xr-x   4 ruiperes  staff    136 29 Jun 00:12 PlaygroundTests
drwxr-xr-x   4 ruiperes  staff    136 29 Jun 00:12 PlaygroundUITests


FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(SRCROOT)/Frameworks/
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` in the xcodeproj includes the path where `Result.framework` is.