# Unable to Import Objective-C Files into Swift project using bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header

I created an objective-C project for socket programming and its working fine now i want to import it into my Swift project where i am using JSQmessageViewController for chating. I copied "AsyncSocket.h" and "AsyncSocket.m" into my swift proejct and imported them in bridging header as well but when i try to use them in my "ViewController.swift" it gives me error 
My bridging Header is working fine because i can use JSQmessageViewController in my "ViewController.swift" without any issues. This is my bridging header

[image]

Build Settings seems fine to me

[image]

But still getting this error

[image]

Comment: Once you have added the .h file to the bridging header there is no need to add an `import` statement to your swift file; the objective c class will be available automatically.

Comment: refer this link,It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/xcode-no-such-module-error-but-the-framework-is-there and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106411/no-such-module-on-xcode-7-beta-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You don't import your Objective-C file directly to your swift file.  Write something like

```
let asyncSocketInstance:AsyncSocket = AsyncSocket()
```

.  Make sure AsyncSocket appears under Compile Sources of Build Phases and its header file is imported in the bridging header file.

Comment: ohh i understand that now thak you soo much it worked. Other wise i was thinking to conver my JSQmessageViewController project into objective-C because i was not able to find any tutorial of JSQmessageViewController in Objective-C