# Errors after updating to Xcode 8: "No such module" and "target overrides the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT`build setting"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

I'm getting `No such module` for Pods when I try to build the project. If I remove the code expecting this Pod, another 'No such module' comes up for another Pod, which means every Pod must be affected. When I type `pod install` I get the following messages:

```
[!] The X target overrides the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` build setting defined in `X’. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `X` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `X'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.
```

I get each of these for both the debug and release versions of my app and the two tests, so 12 messages in total.

I have set `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` and `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` to `NO` and `YES` both in my Build Settings and this did nothing. I also added the following code to my Podfile and it didn't work either:

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'NO'
    end
end
end
```

Comment: Use the `$(inherited)` flag as suggested by the CocoaPods

Answer (score 145):

```
[!] The `X` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `X'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.
```

I had met this problem today. I solved it by

1. Go to Project/Targets -> [Project Name] -> Build Settings.
2. search "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES"
3. click the right of Debug, and selected 'Other', input "$(inherited)"
4. do same with 'Release' and install your pod

You can follow the image below.

---

[image]

Comment: I tried to do this but error "no such module" still appears

Comment: This worked for me to fix the pod install/update. However Xcode (8) then issued a warning to update settings and revert the changes.

Comment: I had to set it this way for the PROJECT, and all TARGETS. And no more warnings in the terminal :)

Comment: Why isn't cocoapods doing this on `init`?

Comment: I get always `No - $(inherited)`  I can't set it to `YES- $(inherited)` like in screenshot

Comment: Just choose Other. Follow my step3

Comment: This worked for me: pod install no longer generates warning. I did it for both of my target settings; App and Tests. I did not do it for the project settings.

Comment: @Chlebta, that happened to me, too, but it was because I was setting the `$(inherited)` under the `Project` section and not under the `Targets` section (as shown in the snapshot in the Projects & Targets list).  Also, having not set the correct `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` variable, cocoapods was still giving me the warning.

Comment: @Chlebta select "Yes" and then select "Other..." now input $(inherited).

Answer (score 21):

The errors you see when running `pod install` should not cause the `No such module` errors. So my guess is that these errors are unrelated.

---

#### To get rid of the `pod install` errors:

This happens because you define a flag in your build settings which overrides that set by CocoaPods. It doesn't matter if you set it to `YES` or `NO`, it will still overwrite the setting from CocoaPods.

**To fix this:**

1. Go to Project/Targets -> [Project Name] -> Build Settings.
2. Find and *click on* the relevant setting (you can use the search box in the top right corner).
3. Press `Backspace` to remove the setting.

You should see the setting going from **bold** to normal font. This means that the setting has been deleted, and is using a default value instead.

Repeat for each flag giving you an error, and rerun `pod install` to verify that it worked.

---

#### Reasons for `No such module` errors:

There are a number of way that this error can occur. Have you looked at these answers to see if any applies to your case? If you report back on that it will be easier to help you.

1. [Xcode : “No such module” error, but the framework is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500227/xcode-no-such-module-error-but-the-framework-is-there)
2. [“no such module” on Xcode 7 beta 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31106411/no-such-module-on-xcode-7-beta-2)

Answer (score 5):

***(Updated as of  July 29, 2018)***

1. Projects/Targets --> Project Name --> Build Settings
2. Build Options
3. Click on *Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries* so that it is highlighted
4. Press the *delete* button on your keyboard

The *Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries* should no longer be **Bold**, and you will no longer receive this warning when performing pod updates or pod installs =)

Comment: Thanks it worked, but it will not effect any other functionality right ?

Comment: @ArivenNadar, no, not that I'm aware of

Comment: 07/10/2017, This solution worked for me in a mixed Swift/Obj C Project/Pods

Comment: I'm still getting warnings 2017/10/23.... To get this working you must go through all targets and make sure they are all not bold. This includes Test as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I worked for me:

```
pod deintegrate || rm -rf Pods
pod install --verbose
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Then I just clean my project and  build it again.

Comment: bit of a shotgun approach, but yeh, a clean install often helps

Comment: it's make a lost of warning to me :(

Comment: @iLandes this is what is worked for me, maybe you are doing something different to get all the lost of warnings

Answer (score -3):

when I import SDWebImage in my project second time,It worn that Module FLAnimatedImage not found,and when I pod install ,it warn  "... ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES ... - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or - Remove the build settings from the target." 
At last, I find the way that  remove the SD completely,specialy in the  finder ,in the pods' products,and delete the project in the simulator , then import SD again.

Comment: So, the steps to fix it are:

1st.- Remove the SD (in the finder)
2nd.- Delete the project in the simulator
3rd.- Import SD again

If so, next time try to edit and give a better format to your answer. Welcome to SO.