# Cocoa Pods - File not found

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I am new to cocoa pods. First time trying. After installing Cocoa pods I just opened terminal and executed cd to current project directory and done pod install. Installation of pod sucess. But still Xcode saying file not found error.[image]

[image]

[image]

How to fix this error in Xcode ? Am I need to anyting else apart from pod install ?

Comment: have you tried `import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit>`

Comment: Delete all entries of FB SDK, clean project, delete derived data and again FB SDK again. It helped me once. Hope same happens for you.

Comment: I'm the creator of AntiCandyCrunch. Can you please tell me witch version of the code are you using? The warnings in Terminal say all. For a starter check this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569743/errors-after-updating-to-xcode-8-no-such-module-and-target-overrides-the-em](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569743/errors-after-updating-to-xcode-8-no-such-module-and-target-overrides-the-em) Let me know if those orange warnings dissapeard after you try to install the pods again.

Comment: where to use $(inherited) flag ? Tried that answer..still same error

Comment: its cocoa pod based project...still error not fixed.