# Xcode and Cocoapods "No such module" error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode8

I recently upgraded to Xcode 8 and an existing project to Swift 3. After having a variety of issues with Cocoapods, I decided to start over from scratch. After running `pod deintegrate` and deleting `Podfile`, `Podfile.lock`, and `[Project].xcworkspace`, I had a blank slate as far as Cocoapods was concerned.

I then took the following actions:

1. Opened a terminal at the project location and ran `pod init`, then `pod install` (using the stub Podfile that `pod init` creates).

   This appeared to be successful, but came with the following two warnings:

`` [!] The `Xena [Debug]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Xena/Pods-Xena.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target. ``

`` [!] The `Xena [Release]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Xena/Pods-Xena.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target. ``

At this point, opening Xcode and building the project gives the "No such module" error, which is entirely expected.

Following the instructions at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569743/errors-after-updating-to-xcode-8-no-such-module-and-target-overrides-the-em) solves this problem and rerunning `pod install` is a success.

2. Closed Xcode, added the modules I'm using to the Podfile (see below), the ran `pod install` again. According to the terminal output, this is successful.
3. Opened Xcode and built the project. I again receive the "No such module" error, specifically `No such module 'ReactiveCocoa'`

   **I have confirmed that the same problem occurs with SnapKit, Hue, KMPlaceholderTextView, KeychainSwift, and Siren, depending on the order of the import statements. For some reason, none of the Google modules are affected by this problem.**

My Podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Xena' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Xena
  pod 'ReactiveCocoa', :git => 'https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.git'
  pod 'SnapKit', '~> 3.0.2'
  pod 'Hue', '~> 2.0.1'
  pod 'KMPlaceholderTextView', '~> 1.3.0'
  pod 'GooglePlacePicker'
  pod 'GooglePlaces'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'KeychainSwift', '~> 7.0'
  pod 'Siren'

  target 'XenaTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'XenaUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: @AnniS Can you provide more details? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: make sure you had followed all the steps mentioned in the https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa

Comment: I have, especially given that the steps that are relevant to me are, in total, "add this line to your Podfile", which I have.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find any solution? I have tried everything. The same project works fine on another computer.

Answer (score 20):

Make sure you are opening `.xcworkspace` and not `.xcodeproj` file.

You may further look into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994331/no-such-module-restkit-with-cocoapods-and-swift).

Also under : Target > General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries
Make sure your frameworks are there. Even `Pods_Xena.framework` is there

Comment: Yep, I always use `.xcworkspace`. Under Linked Frameworks and Libraries I have two entries: `CoreData.framework` and `Pods_Xena.framework`

Comment: Add other frameworks as well, You might have to drag them there. This is the reason they are not working. I had the same issue.

Comment: I've now added all of them, and I still have the same error

Comment: Even added "ReactiveCocoa" ?

Comment: Clean build and then check

Comment: Yep, ReactiveCocoa included. I have deleted Derived Data (just to be sure), cleaned the build folder, and rebuilt, to the same effect.

Comment: Giki graduate would know. Thanks

Comment: @cookiemonsta 

Answer (score 8):

Try:

Xcode ->Preferences ->Location ->DerivedData

open the folder DerivedData and move it to Trash

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

```
platform :iOS, '9.0'
```

Uncommenting the second line in your pod file will help you.