# Xcode - Check Pod Manifest and Frameworks Error

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

My app on the App Store, but I didn't understand why my "Build Phases" section gives "pod install" error in below [CP] areas even I did already that.

[image]

```
diff "${PODS_ROOT}/../Podfile.lock" "${PODS_ROOT}/Manifest.lock" > /dev/null
if [[ $? != 0 ]] ; then
    cat << EOM
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
EOM
    exit 1
fi
```

> After cocoapods update "pod install" gives below warning:

```
[!] The `<project name> [Release]` target overrides the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` build setting defined in `<.xcconfig location>'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Comment: I think you need to  install pod.

Comment: @YogendraGirase I tried many times It doesn't remove this.

Comment: I think first you need to install cocoapods : sudo gem install cocoapods . after that install pod

Comment: @YogendraGirase After doing that "pod install" gives another error on the terminal screen. I updated my question above.

Comment: @YogendraGirase Added '$(inherited)' what it says but still continue [CP] errors in xcode.

Comment: You can check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569743/errors-after-updating-to-xcode-8-no-such-module-and-target-overrides-the-em

Comment: I did everything but still getting same sandbox is not sync warning.