# cocoapods Google Mobile ads does not generate .xcworkspace file

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, cocoapods

I am exporting a project from Unity3d to xcode that uses the last GoogleMobileAds package.
I have installed and updated cocoapods and also have the famous podfile containing de following lines:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
install! 'cocoapods', :integrate_targets => false
platform :ios, ‘8.0’

target ‘MyProject’ do
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.14’
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
end
```

and I run

```
pod install
```

and

```
pod update
```

successfully

dependancies are downloaded alright, as you can see the results below:

```
Updating local specs repositories

CocoaPods 1.2.0.beta.1 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.2.0.beta.1

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Firebase (3.9.0)
Using FirebaseAnalytics (3.5.1)
Using FirebaseCore (3.4.4)
Using FirebaseInstanceID (1.0.8)
Installing Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (7.14.0)
Using GoogleInterchangeUtilities (1.2.2)
Using GoogleSymbolUtilities (1.1.2)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.0)
Generating Pods project
Skipping User Project Integration
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 3 dependencies from the Podfile and 8 total pods installed.
```

According to both cocoapods and google mobile ads documentation, I will need to continue with "MyProject.xcworkspace" but the file is nowhere to be found.

any suggestions?

Comment: Read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10960309/7115714 and comments

Comment: Nope... Neither a file nor a folder called something.xcworkspace appears in my project directory.... the project name also corresponds to the target name in podfile.
Usually it should be created after running pod install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `install! 'cocoapods', :integrate_targets => false` Cocoapods will not create an `xcworkspace` for you.

That's the intended behaviour. You'll even notice this if you follow the command prompt. This line is telling you that no integration is taking place.

`Skipping User Project Integration`

If you want to get an `xcworkspace` just remove `:integrate_targets => false`

Comment: This was the correct answer for me, remove `:integrate_targets => false` and it will generate the `.xcworkspace`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem comes from editing the Podfile using TextEdit.

As it warns you that you should not continue using TextEdit, one could falsely suppose that the program is intelligent enough to understand and correct these unwanted modifications.
This is the solution I have found:

1. delete the Podfile and Podfile.lock from your working directory
2. create a new Podfile using pod init
3. install SublimeText and use it to open the Podfile
4. add the necessary pods for the project
   (I also included the line "use_frameworks!" although it may not be
   needed.)
5. run "pod install" and "pod update"; this time I get

   [!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `Orbit.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.

and the file is now available in project directory

Answer (score 0):

You was used [this](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html) guide for install pod?

Comment: Almost. I also used Google_Mobile_Ads_SDK.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Radu Dita's message. If you do not want that line to be added (so you do not need to delete it later), you need to disable cocoapods integration in "iOS Resolver Settings" by selecting "None", build project and then enable it back "Xcode Workspace". I found this with try and error. I hope my message will save save someone's time